# Bundling of services in Angular 2

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-services

I have a question regarding the best practices for the following situation:

We have multiple components in the same module which use the same of multiple services. Is there a way around injecting each service into each component?

So far I went with a BaseComponent into which I injected each service needed, and which all other components extended to get access to those services.

Is this considered good practice? Is there another way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend extending your Components, as this feels a bit clunky, although technically it would work.

You can however create a BaseService, which injects some other services, and only inject the BaseService in the components. That way, you can create a sort of hierarchy of services.

Keep in mind that injecting is there for a good reason, and you should only inject the services you really need in any component.

Comment: I think it would be even better to avoid inheritance altogether and inject service that simply provide references to or better yet delegates to the other services